# hyperledger composer throws the following errors. What should I do?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Getting this error
You don't seem to have a generator with the name “hyperledger-composer:businessnetwork” installed.
But help is on the way:

You can see available generators via npm search yeoman-generator or via http://yeoman.io/generators/. 
Install them with npm install generator-hyperledger-composer:businessnetwork.

To see all your installed generators run yo without any arguments. Adding the --help option will also show subgenerators.

If yo cannot find the generator, run yo doctor to troubleshoot your system.

Comment: Have you installed the generator with the -g option? " npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer ".

Comment: @RThatcher Yes I did. I too am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Run yo > install a generator > hyperledger

This solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me:

```
$ yo
```

choose:

```
> Install a generator
```

you'll see:

```
? Search npm for generators:
```

type: **hyperledger**

choose:

```
Install one? hyperledger-composer
```

You're done!
Remember, it'll work only if yo is correctly installed, to verify yo's installation you can run:

```
$ yo doctor
```

If you have trouble installing yo you can run the install command as sudo:

```
$ sudo npm install -g yo
```

despite you shouldn't run npm as sudo, sometimes you get EACCESS errors, and run it as super user usually works.

If you actually run npm as sudo dont't forget to go to /usr/lib/node_modules and run

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 yo
```

this will give you permission in yo's folder so you will not have problems running it latter.

hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't find hyperledger when ask me to search for a generator.